# static и переопределение?

Tags: java, static

Все началось с того, что я прочитал про `static` и про то, что методы помеченные `static` не переопределяются. Написал вот такой код, да бы убедиться:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass.run();
        SubClass.run();
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public static void run(){
        System.out.println("А SubClass и не думает оставать");
    }
}

public class SuperClass {
    public static void run(){
        System.out.println("SuperClass бежит");
    }
}
```

Вот что он у меня вывел:

```
SuperClass бежит 
А SubClass и не думает оставать.
```

После этого я задумался почему везде написано что нельзя переопределять, если я переопределил? Но почувствовав себя гением, я зашел на Stackoverflow чтобы спросить совета у гуру разрабов.

Увидел на JavaRush вот такой пример:

```
    class Vehicle{
         public static void  kmToMiles(int km){
              System.out.println("Внутри родительского класса/статического метода");
         }
 }

    class Car extends Vehicle{
         public static void  kmToMiles(int km){
              System.out.println("Внутри дочернего класса/статического метода ");
         } 
}

    public class Demo{
       public static void main(String args[]){
          Vehicle v = new Car();
           v.kmToMiles(10);
      }
}
```

Вообще не понял зачем мы написали `Vehicle v = new Car();` не понял что за конструкция, ибо я всегда создавал объект вот так: `Vehicle v = new Vehicle();`.
Далее в этом же примере идёт `v.kmToMiles(10);` но зачем вообще было создавать объект и через объект вызывать метод если мы работаем со static и "всё" вызывает класс. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: _если я переопределил_ - но ты не переопределил, ты просто создал статический метод у SubClass.

Comment: @Grundy но я унаследовался от SuperClass(a) и сделал всё в точь как у него, только изменил в sout текст, можно развёрнутый ответ?

Comment: `v.kmToMiles(10);` должен вывести `Внутри родительского класса/статического метода` если `kmToMiles` статический метод. И `Внутри дочернего класса/статического метода` если не статический. Т.к. в случае реального переопределения вызывается метод конкретного типа, который по ссылке находится, а в случае статического метода - метод класса, коий является типом для переменной.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо большое, жаль я не очень понял

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван, а что по твоему такое _переопределение_?

Comment: Если вы добавите аннотацию "@Ovveride" над методами, то компилятор вас уведомит о том, что статический метод нельзя переопределить".

Comment: @Grundy определение - это когда мы переопределяем метод(ы) родительского класса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переопределение методов позволяет при вызове метода ориентироваться на его *Run-time* тип.

В то же время, вызов статических функций определяется в *compile-time* время.

Например:

```
class Base{
    public void  kmToMiles(int km){
        System.out.println("Base class");
   }
}

class Derive extends Base{
    public void  kmToMiles(int km){
        System.out.println("Derive class");
    } 
}

public class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Base b = new Derive(); // run-time тип - Derive, compile-time тип - Base
        b.kmToMiles(10); // "Derive class"
    }
}
```

**[пример в работе](https://ideone.com/J6s5EV)**

В данном случае видно, что несмотря на сохранение ссылки в переменную с базовым классом - функция будет вызвана у наследуемого.

В случае же со статическими методами, в момент компиляции будет проверен тип переменной, и так как она объявлена с типом `Base` - метод будет вызван именно этого типа.

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Base b = new Derive(); // run-time тип - Derive, compile-time тип - Base
        b.kmToMiles(10); // "Base class"
    }
}

class Base{
    public static void  kmToMiles(int km){
        System.out.println("Base class");
   }
}

class Derive extends Base{
    public static void  kmToMiles(int km){
        System.out.println("Derive class");
    } 
}
```

**[пример в работе](https://ideone.com/6JK40v)**

Так как определение какой метод будет вызван происходит в момент компиляции, а не в момент выполнения данный случай нельзя назвать *переопредением*, и в данном случае это *перекрытие*, так как метод базового класса *перекрывается* методом наследника

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе некорректный пример который поможет разобраться:

```
SubClass subClass = null;
subClass.run()
```

Тут не будет ошибки NullPointerException как кто-то мог бы подумать, только предупреждение от компилятора. А код выведет "А SubClass и не думает оставать".

```
SubClass subClass = null;
((SupperClass) subClass).run();
```

А этот код выведет: "SuperClass бежит"

Все потому, что эти методы так называемы статические методы классов, компилятор превратит код выше в такие однозначные вызовы:

```
SubClass.run();
SupperClass.run();
```

А вот методы экземпляров классов можно подменять/переопределять, например подменим метод run() класса Thread на свой собственный:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello new thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
}.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Логика в классе Thread не знает что мы что-то там подменили, она вызовет вроде свой метод run() а по факту будет исполнен наш.