# Как реализовать метод из интерфейса рекурсивным образом

Tags: java, рекурсия, интерфейс

У меня есть интерфейс с двумя методами, метод `void flood` имеет параметр `String map` который представляет площадь из `LAND` и `WATER`. Метод `void flood` вызывается пока весь `LAND` будет `WATER`.
Первый вопрос: Как сделать чтоб `flood` метод сам себя вызывал?
Второй вопрос: Как метод `FloodFill` может вернуть экземпляр `FloodFill`? Это ведь интерфейс.

```
public interface FloodFill{
    void flood(final String map, final FloodLogger logger);

    static FloodFill getInstance() {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    char LAND = '█';
char WATER = '░';
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: если у тебя FloodFill интерфейс, то ты должен наследовать от него свой класс и в нем определять методы описанные в интерфейсе.

Comment: А как переопределить метод static FloodFill getInstance()

Comment: Статические методы нельзя в принципе переопределить. Они привязаны к классу, их нет смысла переопределять. Пользуйтесь поиском по сайту, конкретно вопрос про static и переопределение задавался и уже есть ответ. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/914169/218971 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1128839/218971